# Detecting which way mouse is scrolled

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, mousewheel

There is only one method in the MouseWheelListener interface. I need to do different things depending on whether the mouse is scrolled up or down. How to achieve such a thing? Just for information, I have a JPanel inside a JScrollPane. I will use mouse wheel motion to zoom in or out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mouseWheelMoved method takes a MouseWheelEvent parameter. There are fields in that parameter that you can use to determine the direction of the scrolling (see [MouseWheelEvent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelEvent.html)). So once you know which direction the wheel moved in, you can decide what action to perform.

Comment: Specifically the getWheelRotation() method. From the Javadoc, "negative values if the mouse wheel was rotated up/away from the user, and positive values if the mouse wheel was rotated down/ towards the user"

Comment: If possible, this answer would be a bit better with a code example

Answer (score 2):

```
event.getWheelRotation()
```

-1 = Up

1 = Down